# Custom inputs do not change when clicked

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm trying to get my custom buttons to change colors when clicked using only HTML/CSS - I have it written so that the outline should turn green but it isn't working (the buttons are being treated like static boxes?).

I'm trying to get something to this effect: 
[image]

But am getting stuck on styling/how to get the "Not at all" etc text to show.

EDIT: Results with cale_b's changes:

[image]

```css
    .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.radio-toolbar label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5.5vw;
  height:3.8vw;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  font-family:Avenir Next;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom:5vh;
}

.radio-toolbar p{
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  line-height:3.8vw;
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.radio-cls {
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="1test" name="a">
<label for="1test" class="radio-cls"><p>1</p></label>

<input type="radio" id="2test" name="b">
<label for="2test" class="radio-cls"><p>2</p></label>

<input type="radio" id="3test" name="c">
<label for="3test" class="radio-cls"><p>3</p></label>

<input type="radio" id="4test" name="d">
<label for="4test" class="radio-cls"><p>4</p></label>
```

Comment: There is no radio buttons, i see readionum, with a display none

Comment: And you can't have multiple elements with the same `id`, that's invalid HTML.  Also `<bel>` isn't a standard element type, perhaps you meant `<label>`?

Comment: I didn't want to use label because there are other labels in the CSS that have different formats, so having different labels messes up the styling of everything else

Comment: Well, since `bel` is not a HTML element, it has no functionality whatsoever. Yeah, you can style it, but it is not clickable without a lot of JavaScript effort. And then it still wouldn't be valid HTML.

Comment: For this to work, you need to do three things: 1. Each input should be made to a `radio` type. 2. Each input should get a _unique_ ID.  3. Each `bel` element should be made into a `label`, with the `for` properly addressing the correct radio.  It does not matter that there are other labels, simply add a `class="radio-control"` or similar to these labels and style appropriately.

Comment: Got a jquery solution if needed

Comment: I can't use JQuery unfortunately because I'm doing this in an EJS file and adding JS doesn't seem to be working in any of the files...

Comment: @cale_b I addedmy changes - how would I use "radio-control" exactly? I named it "radio-cls"

Comment: `radio-control` is _purely for styling_.  Change the class to be whatever you want, but be sure to update it in both your CSS and your HTML

Answer (score 2):

Keep to the basics, and this is easy enough.

In the snippet below, I've:

1. Put everything in a container, so I can address it with a css class. This will allow you to style the labels however you like, regardless of other form label styles.
2. Paired the input (which I switched to traditional radio inputs) with the labels (which I switched to traditional labels) using the proper "id" and "for" attributes.
3. Applied styling to show how you can get the appearance you desire.

```css
.radio-control input {
  display: none !important;
}

.radio-control label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.radio-control input:checked+label {
  background: #aaa;
}

.radio-control label:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.radio-control label:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-control">
  <input type="radio" id="testa" name="test" value="a">
  <label for="testa">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="testb" name="test" value="b">
  <label for="testb">2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="testc" name="test" value="c">
  <label for="testc">3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="testd" name="test" value="d">
  <label for="testd">4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I added a picture of what happens once I change it to this — do you know what could possibly be making it look like that? I followed your code exactly.

Comment: First - did you click `run code snippet` above? You'll see that the radio inputs _do not show_.  So, I'm guessing that something about your CSS is either overriding the CSS, or you put this css _before_ other css, that may be overriding it.  You can use your browser's developer tools to "inspect" the radio input, and see which styles are affecting the input (right-click on the radio, click "inspect", then in the panel below you can see the markup, styles, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Below might be something what you want to acheive

```css
.hello{
  width: 5.5vw;
  height:3.8vw;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid black;

}

.hello:focus{
  
   border: solid 2px green;
}

.hello::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
   color:black;
   
}

.hello:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
   color:black;
}

.hello::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;  
   color:black;
}

.hello:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center; 
   color:black;
}
```

```html
<h4>Below might be something what you want to acheive </h4>


<input type="text" class="hello" placeholder="1">
<input type="text" class="hello" placeholder="2" >
<input type="text" class="hello" placeholder="3" >
<input type="text" class="hello" placeholder="4">
```

Comment: The snippet does not appear to work properly, at least in FireFox.

Comment: Google chrome here and same

Comment: @MrLister if I hide the inputs, you wont know where to click in order to show the effect, you can first use the css to bring your input behind the bel 1 2 3 4 and then might wanna hide

Comment: @cale_b yes it does not working in some old/some browsers. I just wanted to point out the question asker where is he doing mistake. Once again above is not the optimal solution. He should use the input type text label, css it, disable it to acheive something like he wants

Comment: So why not putting this in a comment instead of adding an answer with no solution?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO updated the answer, something he might want to acheive and thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a slightly different code inside a `fieldset`

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqQexe)

**Markup**

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" id="vote-1" />
  <label for="vote-1">1 <span>Not at all</span></label>

  <input type="radio"  name="vote" value="2" id="vote-2" />
  <label for="vote-2">2</label>

  <input type="radio" name="vote" value="3" id="vote-3" />
  <label for="vote-3">3 <span>Very much</span></label>

</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
input { margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; z-index: -1; clip: rect(0,0,0,0); width: 0; top: -100vw;}

fieldset {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   border: 1px  #d8d8d8 solid;
   border-radius: 5px;
   font-size: 0;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

label:not(first-of-type) {
  border-left: 1px #d8d8d8 solid; 
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;   
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 25px;
}

label span {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 1em);
  font-size: .75rem;
}

label:first-of-type span { left: 0; }
label:last-of-type span { right: 0; }

:checked + label {
   background: #f2f1f9;
}
```

---

**Final result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! Would it be possible to use a different name for label? I don't want the labels for this one element to change the labels of everything else on the page, which this seems to do whenever I try it.

Comment: this works using the for attribute of the label elements, so if you don't want use them you need to use js

Comment: I can't use JS unfortunately because I'm doing this in an EJS file and adding JS doesn't seem to be working in any of the files...  :(

Comment: if you have other names you can use yours, the example will work anyway. have tried to just adapt my example with your code?